# Is it possible to have Art Direction reassessed when font size changes by button click javascript event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Art Direction and Responsive Images code works, (in em units even,) but it seems like it doesn't re-assess when the font-size of the `html` element changes, (ie. when the size of an em changes.)  I would like for increasing the font size to cause an image to use a higher quality version if merited, and/or use an art-directed (if that's a term) version if merited (ie. zoom-in;) and if font is decreased, to zoom back out if merited.

I switched to em units in the source `html` elements' media and sizes attributes.  I used calc to subtract 1 pixel, rather than using a decimal number of em units.

I made a jsfiddle to combine the html, the css, and the javascript which is relevant, seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/gt6omaez/

```
HTML
<div class=testing-area><!--
     --><a
            class=yard-sign
            title="Click to visit Campaign Page"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
            href="https://howiehawkins.us"
        ><!--
         --><picture><!--
             --><source
                    type="image/png"
                    media="(max-width:calc(20em-1px))"
                    srcset="https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo.png 110w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo-146.png 146w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo-175.png 175w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo-218.png 218w
                    "
                    sizes="6.875em"
                ><!--
             --><source
                    type="image/png"
                    media="(min-width:20em)"
                    srcset="https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020.png 290w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-386.png 386w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-463.png 463w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-579.png 579w
                    "
                    sizes="18.125em"
                ><!--
             --><img
                    alt="Howie Hawkins 2020 campaign logo"
                    src="https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo.png"
                    srcset="https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo.png 110w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo-146.png 146w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo-175.png 175w,
                        https://www.stevemario.com/images/howie-hawkins-2020-logo-218.png 218w
                    "
                    sizes="6.875em"
                ><!--
         --></picture><!--
     --></a><!--
     --><div class=font-resize-buttons-area><!--
         --><span>Font Size:</span><!--
         --><a
                class=font_increase_button
                title="Click to increase font size"
            ><!--
            -->+<!--
         --></a><!--
         --><a
                class=font_decrease_button
                title="Click to decrease font size"
            ><!--
             -->-<!--
         --></a><!--
     --></div><!--
 --></div>

Javascript
document.documentElement.style.fontSize='12pt';function increase_font_size(){document.documentElement.style.fontSize=parseFloat(document.documentElement.style.fontSize)+0.5+'pt';}function decrease_font_size(){document.documentElement.style.fontSize=parseFloat(document.documentElement.style.fontSize)-0.5+'pt';}document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){var font_increase_buttons=document.getElementsByClassName('font_increase_button');for(const font_increase_button of font_increase_buttons){font_increase_button.addEventListener('click',function(){increase_font_size();});}var font_decrease_buttons=document.getElementsByClassName('font_decrease_button');for(const font_decrease_button of font_decrease_buttons){font_decrease_button.addEventListener('click',function(){decrease_font_size();});}});

CSS
body
{
margin:0;
background-color:#00AE00
}
.testing-area
{
padding:0.5em;
box-sizing:border-box;
max-width:320px;
background-color:black;
margin:0 auto;
line-height:1
}
.yard-sign
{
display:inline-block;
padding:0.21875em 0.4375em
}
.yard-sign:hover
{
background-color:#00AE00;
color:black
}
.yard-sign:hover picture
{
filter:invert(1)
}
.yard-sign img
{
height:2.8125em;
vertical-align:top
}
.font-resize-buttons-area
{
display:inline-block;
font-size:3em
}
.font-resize-buttons-area > *
{
display:inline-block;
box-sizing:border-box;
min-width:1em;
min-height:1em
}
.font-resize-buttons-area > span
{
color:white
}
.font-resize-buttons-area > a
{
color:#00AE00;
text-align:center
}
.font-resize-buttons-area > a:hover
{
background-color:#00AE00;
color:black
}
```

There is an `<a>` tag link to a campaign's webpage, and it encloses an image.  The image is of the campaign logo.  The image uses the `<picture>` tag, with children of 2 `<source>` tags w/ `media` attributes (for art direction,) and an `<img>` tag for browsers that don't support it.  Each of these have `srcset` atrributes, and`sizes`, all are in em units.  The `<img>` also has `alt` attribute set, and `src` attribute set.

Then, there are buttons for increasing and decreasing the font size.  There is javascript to add click events to these that will do those operations.

There is css to present the logo as used, but also to demonstrate the problem.  I use a container with a `max-width` style of 320px so that a critical threshold can be tested.  320px is the threshold where a complete logo will be shown, ie. with the descriptor.  Less than 320px will show an incomplete logo, ie without the descriptor.  If you move the bar of the jsfiddle, and resize the frame width, you can see the art direction working, (or at least I hope it does for you, and not just me.)

The container will allow you to keep the image an area of 320px recognizable (background is black,) for if you increase the font size, by clicking the button.

When resizing the font larger, I see the complete logo remain, and overflow the container, rather than there being some art direction reassessment to show the incomplete logo.

Decreasing the font size, does not seem to cause art direction reassessment either, as lowering the frame width below 320px, and then decreasing the font size multiple times does not show the complete logo.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use css variables in the `media` attribute of the `<source>` elements, but that didn't do it either.  I have written javascript code to change the `media` and `sizes` attributes, and it works as I wanted.  For those interested: https://jsfiddle.net/u7arm0cf/